# Index DataFrame with list or series of boolean values (not statements)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which a certain column is fed to a filtering function that returns a series of boolean values (not a boolean statements).

EG: my filter returns

```
0   True,
1   False,
2   True
```

How can I get only the dataframe rows in which my filter series is true?
In the example above, I would have a dataframe with row index 1 removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if both `indexes`are same:

```
df = df[boolean_ser]
```

If not and lenght is same:

```
df = df[boolean_ser.values]
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
boolean_ser = pd.Series([True, False, True], index=df.index)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  8  8  3  7
1  7  0  4  2
2  5  2  2  2
```

```
boolean_ser = pd.Series([True, False, True], index=df.index)
print (boolean_ser)
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

df1 = df[boolean_ser]
print (df1)
   A  B  C  D
0  8  8  3  7
2  5  2  2  2
```

---

```
boolean_ser = pd.Series([True, False, True], index=[8,9,10])
print (boolean_ser)
8      True
9     False
10     True
dtype: bool

df1 = df[boolean_ser.values]
print (df1)
   A  B  C  D
0  8  8  3  7
2  5  2  2  2
```

List works perfectly too (if same length):

```
print (boolean_list)
[True, False, True]

df1 = df[boolean_list]
print (df1)
   A  B  C  D
0  8  8  3  7
2  5  2  2  2
```